# jquery set url to submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a form with this validation

## jquery

```
$("#aioForm").on('submit',function(e){
        var errorCount = 0;
        $('span.errorMessage').text('');
        // checkign for multiple select [now you have one]
        var select = $('#addIO select').filter(function(){
            return this.selectedIndex == 0;
        }).next('span').text('Please select a cell');
        // checking for inputs
        var input = $("#aioForm input[type=text]").filter(function() {
            return !this.value;
        }).next('span').text("fill the name please");
        // no error checking
        if(input.length==0 && select.length == 0){
            $(this)[0].submit(); // submit form if no error
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

if there is no error i want to set the url to submit before submit , i mean before the statement

```
$(this)[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$(this).submit();
```

**Edit:** *(After OP comments)*

If you want to submit your form with some specific values from javascript:

Add two fields in your form like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='currentRelation' id='currentRelation'>
<input type='hidden' name='currentConcept' id='currentConcept'>
```

Now in jQuery you need to do this before submit:

```
// Get values from HTML (According to your previous question)
var ioAddConcept = $(".ioAddConcept").html();
var ioAddRelation = $(".ioAddRelation").html();

// Set these values to hidden fields
$('#ioAddConcept').text( ioAddConcept );
$('#ioAddRelation').text( ioAddRelation );

// Now submit form
$(this).submit();
```

Now on server side:

```
print_r( $_POST ); 
// OR 
print_r( $_GET );
```

Comment: hi again man , i tested [0] and it works , i want to put the currentConcept and currentRelation in the url :)

Comment: Please review the edited answer. Hope it will help this time :)

Comment: your code works excelent , but there is one thing , please check my jquery code , the currentConcept and currentRelation are in a loop so i can't guess how many hidden input  i have to make , and in this case the name should be currentConcpet[] , currentRelation[] cos i have to send an array that generated dynamicly , very thank you

Comment: i solve it `            var currentconcepts = new Array();
            $(".ioAddConcept").each(function(index){
                currentconcepts[index] = $(this).html();
            });
            var currentrelations = new Array();
            $(".ioAddRelation").each(function(index){
                currentrelations[index] = $(this).html();
            });
            //$(this)[0].submit(); // submit form if no error
            $(this).attr('action', 'http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/addIO/'+currentconcepts+'/'+currentrelations ).submit();`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(input.length==0 && select.length == 0){
   $(this).attr('action', 'url_to_submit').submit(); 
}
```

Comment: @LinCR `action` is the `form` attribute where to submit form

Comment: ok i got you , so even if i put this in my html code `<form action="new.php"` then the submit will take the url you put in ur code right ?